# Why should we install frontend libraries?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, npm, vue-component

I'm developping a web page using Vue.js, without backend (for the moment).
I need tabs, so 've looked at [vue-tabs-component](https://github.com/spatie/vue-tabs-component).

But to [install](https://github.com/spatie/vue-tabs-component#installation) it I need to :

```
npm install vue-tabs-component --save
```

How will this library be served to users ? They won't have npm installed nor `npm install vue vue-tabs-components` while navigating.

I'm developping only the frontend, therefore I don't need npm and I developp from several computers, several haven't npm.

### Is there a way to use library only with `<script src=...>` ?

I took [vue-tabs-component](https://github.com/spatie/vue-tabs-component) as example but my question is a general one: why have I to **install frontend** if it's gonna be served to client without them installing it ?

Comment: That's a lot of questions rolled in to one: "how to serve a library from a third party source", "how to serve a library to users", "how does a webserver work", "I need a tutorial on front end development", "CDN vs direct serving of assets", etc. etc. Please narrow it down.

Comment: when you will build your app it will create a bundle js file it will contain all of your javascript. so your user does not need to install anything

Comment: The official tutorial have it in second part https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/ that named "Getting Started"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word 'install' might cause some confusion for you here. `npm install some-front-end-library` downloads the files of our imaginary `some-front-end-library` package (e.g. a vue component).

After 'installing' (downloading the package), you reference to these files in your Vue project. E.g.

```
import somefrontendlibrary from 'some-front-end-library'

Vue.use(somefrontendlibrary);
```

You need to download/install the package first on the computer you're developing on, in order to be able to import them in your project. Just like you would download any other third party script which you later add using a script-tag.

When you build your project (npm run build), a vendor.js file will be generated (among others) which includes the some-front-end-library package. This file includes the package which you've installed (and added through `Vue.use()`).

Your final build (`npm run build`) will have an index.html file with a  `<script src="vendor.js" />` tag.

Comment: good explanation thanks

Comment: Yes good explanations thanks. A little "off-topic" question: the doc says to `import {Tabs, Tab} from 'vue-tabs-component';` but it doesn't work. `import {Tabs, Tab} from './nodes_modules/vue-tabs-component/dist/index.js';` does, is it "the normal way" to do things ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't point to your node directory directly. Are you importing in your main.js file?

Comment: I completely missed the part where I should "build" the app, so now I'm using webpack and `import {Tabs, Tab} from 'vue-tabs-component';` works well, after building. I was definitely ignorant of these front-end "builds". I used to work with jQuery :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the module in order to use it. If, for example, you needed vue-tabs-components somewhere in your web app, you are going to need that source code for that module in order to use the tabs.

When it's served to the client, the code gets packaged and bundled so it's true, they don't need npm, but you do as the developer.

And regardless of if you are front-end or not, if you are using Javascript, you're more likely than not going to need NPM at one point in the development process.

If you want to use CDN's, you could check https://cdnjs.com/

There are CDN's of some NPM front end libraries, but it's not always assured you'll find what you're looking for.